# Swift class property reference points disappear after init method

Tags: ios, c, swift, pjsip

First of all I am not an IOS developer so my knowledge is lacking.
I do apologise if this question is trivial but I don't understand the system enough to know how to even debug an issue like that, so thank you for any time spent on my issue.

I was tasked with writing an VoIP app for IOS using PJSIP library.

My mockup function worked fine and I began to sort things into their own classes where it all started to fall apart.

The C library requires a lot of referenced variables/pointers. With my new  instantiated class if I put everything inside the init() constructor it works. But when I start to separate some parts to seperate methods inside the same class the variables seem to change reference points.

Here's a mockup written in notepad since I cannot provide the code itself and at this hour I don't have access to the Mac:

```
class Account {
    var accId: c_library_type = 0
    var accCfg: c_library_type2 = c_library_type2()

    init()
    {
        c_config_setting_defaults(&self.accCfg)
        //other code
    }

    public func register()
    {
        c_register_method(&self.accId, &self.accCfg) //Throws "exc_bad_access code=1 address=0x0"
    }   
}

//Somewhere else in the code

var account: Account = Account()
account.register()
```

If I were to do

```
class Account {
    var accId: c_library_type = 0
    var accCfg: c_library_type2 = c_library_type2()

    init()
    {
        c_config_setting_defaults(&self.accCfg)
        //other code
        c_register_method(&self.accId, &self.accCfg)
    }   
}

//Somewhere else in the code

var account: Account = Account()
```

There is no issue and the c_register_method works as expected.

I would really appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Edit: The library c file and methods which throw the memory exception:
https://github.com/chakrit/pjsip/blob/master/pjsip/src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_acc.c#L116
https://github.com/chakrit/pjsip/blob/master/pjsip/src/pjsip/sip_util.c#L435

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?  As far as I know there should be no difference between the first and second two.

Comment: I am not sure If I can since I am being held by the licensing. Hence a mockup instead of the code. I just asked since this might have been an issue with a language quirk I didn't know about. The whole code amounts to the examples I gave. The "working" and not working mockups are different in the exact same way the real code is. Moving the second c method from swift method to swift init works while the execution of said c method inside method other than init does not.

Comment: There's no language quirk I know of; in order for us to be able to help, you'll have to mock up enough of the C library for us to see what's going on.  As this question currently stands, there's not really anything we can do to help.

Comment: I might be able to pass this though my supervisor tomorrow. If I remember correctly the C library does a movq between it's variable and the passed UnsafeMutablePointer. I'll edit the question with the library's method github link in a sec

Comment: If you use the first example and call your `register()` function at the end of `init()` does it work?

Comment: It doesn't. It only works if I copy the code from register() to the init(). I also tried moving every single variable outside init to class in case anything got destroyed after init due to not being a class parameter but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from our C developers we've found the reason for this issue.

Swift when variable is passed to a method - copies the root of the reference but holds the same references for it's children which caused issues with how C library checked the reference values. This didn't happen when everything was in one method because only local references were passed and they were not copied.

Example:

```
variable1 :: refId = 0x001
variable1.prop1 :: refId = 0x0011
variable1.prop2 :: refId = 0x0012
variable1.prop3 :: refId = 0x0013

Reference passed to the C library:

(copy) variable1 :: refId = 0x002
variable1.prop1 :: refId = 0x0011
variable1.prop2 :: refId = 0x0012
variable1.prop3 :: refId = 0x0013
```

The library checked if an array reference point was different then first value reference point. If so it assumed that the array was not empty.

Since the main reference was copied hence had different reference point, the code assumed there was some value which in fact didn't exist and we got bad_access due to trying to access a non-existant reference.

The issue was solved with changing the register() method to receive the parameters as inout instead of using self.

Example based on previous mockup :

```
class Account {
    var accId: c_library_type = 0
    var accCfg: c_library_type2 = c_library_type2()

    init()
    {
        c_config_setting_defaults(&self.accCfg)
        //other code
    }

    public func register(id: inout c_library_type, cfg: inout c_library_type2)
    {
        c_register_method(&id, &cfg)
    }   
}

//Somewhere else in the code

var account: Account = Account()
account.register(id: &account.accId, cfg: &account.accCfg)
```

Thank you for your time to anyone who commented on the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see the reason of using & operator as reference types are by default pass by reference and you only need & operator when you need to work with value types to pass their memory address as a reference to be modified. I guess this should fix problem if the function is not taking value types in C.

Comment: Sadly the C library requires an UnsafePointers/UnsafeMutablePointers and just passing the variable passes a c_library_type instead of UnsafePointer<c_library_type>